# SDL specified window size and position

Tags: c, position, window, size, sdl

So my homework is to make Ludo in C on VS2017 with SDL1.2. The way it works is that there is a window with the board on it, initialised this way:

```
SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(751, 751, 0, SDL_ANYFORMAT);
```

The other window is the command prompt (it's a console application), in which all inputs go, using scanf. My probem is that the two windows, although somewhat randomly, always pop up overlapping each other. Is there any way for me to specify the windows' sizes and initial positions on the screen, just to make it look nicer? (The SDL window already has a fixed size of course.)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hi there,**

You could position the cmd prompt by doing the following:
windows `->` type "CMD" `->` right click, open file location `->` right click again, properties and then choose the layout menu.

[image: this is what you'll see]

Uncheck the 'Let system position window' and you're good to go.

Comment: Hey! That is useful, but I'm looking for a way to set the positions in the code, so if I were to send the game to others, they would also get the same window positions when starting up the game.